# How to convert dataframe column with dictionary to rows and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in this format:

| name | T |
| --- | --- |
| First | [{col1: '1', col2: '2'}, {col1: '6', col2: '7'}, {col1: '9', col2: '2'}] |
| Second | [{col1: '88', col2: '277'}, {col1: '889', col2: '290'}] |

I want to convert it to this dataframe:

| name | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | '1' | '2' |
| First | '6' | '7' |
| First | '9' | '2' |
| Second | '88' | '277' |
| Second | '889' | '290' |

how can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: How does your data look before you convert it to a dataframe? I think its possible, but it would involve a lot of fiddling. If you can flatten the data beforehand it might make things easier.

Comment: You should check on `json_normalize` part of pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You can first [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the dataframe and then convert the dictionaries to columns by applying `Series`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['First', 'Second'],
        'T': [[{'col1': '1', 'col2': '2'}, {'col1': '6', 'col2': '7'}, {'col1': '9', 'col2': '2'}],
              [{'col1': '88', 'col2': '277'}, {'col1': '889', 'col2': '290'}]]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df1 = df.explode('T')
df1 = pd.concat([df1.name, df1['T'].apply(pd.Series)], 1)
```

Result:

```
     name col1 col2
0   First    1    2
0   First    6    7
0   First    9    2
1  Second   88  277
1  Second  889  290
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to get required dataframe. But the input has to be `dictionary`.

```
df_dict = df.to_dict("records")
df_dict
[{'name': 'First',
  'T': [{'col1': '1', 'col2': '2'},
   {'col1': '6', 'col2': '7'},
   {'col1': '9', 'col2': '2'}]},
 {'name': 'Second',
  'T': [{'col1': '88', 'col2': '277'}, {'col1': '889', 'col2': '290'}]}]
```

In `json_normalize`, pass the dictionary, column to be `json_normalize`ed and then the other columns to be included

```
pd.json_normalize(df_dict, 'T', ['name']).reindex(columns=['name', 'col1', 'col2'])

    name    col1   col2
0   First   1      2
1   First   6      7
2   First   9      2
3   Second  88     277
4   Second  889    290
```